# Several virtual hosts on the same port with Apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, wamp, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I'm trying to do something simple with virtual hosts in Apache 2.4 (using Wampserver 2.5)

I want to be able to have several virtual hosts and access them simply by :

- www.project1.dev
- www.project2.dev

So I made the following configuration in `httpd.conf` by reading the [official guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) :

```
NameVirtualHost \*:80

#
# Project 1
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myProject1/"
    ServerName www.project1.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/project1-error_log "
    CustomLog "logs/project1-access_log" common
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/myProject1/">
      AllowOverride all
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#
# Project 2
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myProject2/"
    ServerName www.project2.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/project2-error_log "
    CustomLog "logs/project2-access_log" common
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/myProject2/">
      AllowOverride all
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added them to my `hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 http://project1.dev
127.0.0.1 http://project2.dev
```

But while I'm testing after restart wamp services, both http://project1.dev and http://project2.dev point at `C:/wamp/www/myProject1/`

The second path `C:/wamp/www/myProject2/` related to `project2.dev` seems to be ignored.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: `*:80`. No. You need to specify the **host**.

Comment: How you do virtual hosts keeps changing every time they release a new version of Apache. I expect it to change again in a week or so. You need to read the documentation of your current version and follow it exactly. You can't use older or newer documentation because it won't be formatted correctly.

Comment: `\*:80`? Try eliminating the ``\``. What you put tinto the `NVH` directive has to be EXACTLY matched by the `<VirtualHost>` line...

Comment: @kainaw I have Apache 2.4.9 and the documentation I've read is the good one I guess : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: @MarcB According to the doc, the `\*` is a wildcard specifying all IP addresses.

Comment: yes, but `\*` is not "all ips". not even sure apache would like that line.

Comment: Well, I've just removed the `\ ` but didn't change anything :/

Comment: I believe that version uses the *:80 format. However, you need to define both "ServerName mydomain.com" and "ServerName www.mydomain.com". I've had some that were picky and I had to define two separate virtualhosts, one with www and one without www.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not defined http://project2.dev anywhere - just http://www.project2.dev. So Apache defaults back to first config as it can't find a match.

Add the following config to the first vhost:

```
ServerAlias project1.dev
```

and similarly this to the second:

```
ServerAlias project2.dev
```

Then restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that as of Apache 2.4 the `NameVirtualHost *:80` syntax is no longer required or allowed! It throws an error and causes Apache not to start. The error will appear in the `apache error log` if you look for it.

Oh and `NameVirtualHost \*:80` was never right!

So just remove the line `NameVirtualHost \*:80` completely.

As soon as you define a Virtual Host, the localhost in `httpd.conf` gets ignored so you should define that in `httpd-vhost.conf` as well, otherwise the other 2 VH defs look fine, except for the `ServerName` and missing `ServerAlias` and the missing `Options`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride all
      Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#
# Project 1
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myProject1/"
    ServerName project1.dev
    ServerAlias www.project1.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/project1-error_log "
    CustomLog "logs/project1-access_log" common
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/myProject1/">
      AllowOverride all
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#
# Project 2
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myProject2/"
    ServerName project2.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/project2-error_log "
    CustomLog "logs/project2-access_log" common
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/myProject2/">
      AllowOverride all
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Quote: *But while I'm testing after restart wamp services, both http://project1.dev and http://project2.dev point at C:/wamp/www/myProject1/*

If there is an error in your VH definitions, Apache will default to the first correctly defined VH in the httpd-vhosts.conf, so thats what is probably happening

As to your `HOSTS` file it should include references to the IPV4 and IPV6 stack, especially as windows seems to use the IPV6 stack more and more, afterall that where we are moving to, eventually, and it should not include `httpd://` so it should be like this :-

```
#IPV4 stack ip addresses
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 project1.dev
127.0.0.1 project2.dev

#IPV6 stack ip addresses
::1 localhost
::1 project1.dev
::1 project2.dev
```

Once you have changed the HOSTS file, you either need to reboot, or do the following in a command windows launches with "Run as Administrator"

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```